# How to navigate back to specific Activity after app has been in background?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am having a problem where when I suspend my application for a few minutes (having it stay in the background), when I bring it back to the foreground, I want it to always return to a particular activity. Right now, if I am on a particular fragment called `Fragment A`, and I want to navigate to my `HomeActivity`, I thought getting calling an `Intent` from `Fragment A` in `onResume` would work because whenever I thought that whenever I resume my activity from being in the background for a few minutes, that my Intent would trigger and take me back to the `HomeActivity`. This was my attempt:

FragmentA.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
        if(intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Right now, it seems as if when I load up my app, my Fragment gets called when coming out of background, but not the "Home" screen that I want it to be called after I have my app come from the background to the foreground. By the way, the `HomeActivity` in my Android Manifest does not have the following:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

As this is for my login activity when the app first boots up.

However, this seems to give my app a white screen where none of my UI shows, and eventually crashes my app. Is there any way I can always navigate back to an Activity in ANY fragment that I am in after the app comes to the foreground after being in the background (paused, if you will) for a few minutes? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @FabinPaul yes, but I am just wondering why you ask this as I don't see why orientationn would affect anything...but I could be wrong! I may decide to restrict orientation changes in the future though.

Comment: From what I understood, onSaveInstanceState is called before app is destroyed in the background. And when user returns to application, activity's/fragment's onCreate is called. The bundle saved during onSaveInstanceState is supplied as params to onCreate which is null when activity is created using intent. (except when activity is recreated during orientation change). So based on the value of onCreate param (bundle) you can start home actiivty

Comment: If you plan on restricting orientation changes, I may able to give you a solution.

Comment: @FabinPaul sure, I wouldn't mind restricting orientation. I will be open to it! To respond to your first comment, that makes things difficult though because if I have logic to navigate back to the `HomeActivity`in `onCreate`, I can never reach my Fragment class unless I set some sort of flag during `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: can't you finish the activity on Resume function and by intent start it again just after finish in onResume? Like : onResume { getActivity.finish(), now start the activity with intent in next line, use only if you want save instance = null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When application goes into background, activity/fragment savedStateInstance is called and `outState` bundle is saved.

When application is resumed, activity/fragment `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is called. In this case `savedInstanceState`, is not null. If activity was started using intent, `savedInstanceState` would have been null. This is the reason why even though application was destroyed in the background, when application resumes, edittext will contain the text previously entered. (activity/fragment saved its ui state before being destroyed, so that it can restore ui when user returns to it).

In your fragment,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (savedInstanceState != null)       {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

should start HomeActivity when application is destroyed in background.

**Update**
You can apply the same logic in your activity, rather than repeating it in every fragment. i.e

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 if (savedInstanceState != null)       {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**Note:** You must know that when activity is created during orientation changes, `savedInstanceState` is not null. So this solution only works if orientation is locked.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi, I tried your method but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I placed the above code in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` instead of the `onCreate` method because that is how my fragment is created. I have a print statement right before `startActivity(intent)` that seems to print. However, in the `onCreate` method of my `HomeActivity.class`, I have a print statement in the `onCreate` method of my class and that doesn't seem to print. Is there any reason why this wouldn't happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution actually works. The issue is, if I switch between my fragments and I have this code above in each of the fragments, I get moved back to the `HomeActivity` frequently.

Comment: Try moving the code to `onCreate` rather than `onCreatView`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragment use BackStack

```
  String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
        if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();

        }
```

Use this below code wherever you want to remove existing fragmets.

```
 if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();      
}
```

Comment: Where would I use this? in `onResume` method of the Fragment?

Comment: Yes you can use this in onResume and also in onDetach